# Javascript context within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am binding a function to an event.

```
$('div.my_div').bind("mouseenter", timerFunc);
```

The problem that I have is that my context changes and I cannot access my elements.  I must admit that javascript context is terribly confusing to me:

```
function timerFunc() {
    //alert('Square ' + $(this).attr('data-somevalue') + ' named function called!');
    var count_to = 10;
    var count = 0;
    var countup = setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        $(this).find('.countup').html(count + ' seconds!'); // <-- trying to access THIS square
        //self.find('.countup').html(count + ' seconds!'); // <-- trying to access THIS square
        if (count == count_to) {
            count = 0;
        }
    }, 750);
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store `$(this)` in a variable and use it in your nested function:

```
function timerFunc() {
    //alert('Square ' + $(this).attr('data-somevalue') + ' named function called!');
    var elem = $(this);//$(this) is stored in elem variable
    var count_to = 10;
    var count = 0;
    var countup = setInterval(function () {
        count++;
    //so you can use it here in nested function
        elem.find('.countup').html(count + ' seconds!'); // <-- trying to access THIS square
        //self.find('.countup').html(count + ' seconds!'); // <-- trying to access THIS square
        if (count == count_to) {
            count = 0;
        }
    }, 750);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` executes in global context that is `window`, so `this` is `window`. So cache the variable and use it instead

```
var that = this;
var countup = setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    $(that).find('.countup').html(count + ' seconds!');
    if(count == count_to) {
       count = 0;
    }
}, 750);
```